# NavigateToString PDF raises System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, pdf, webview2

I have once managed to show a PDF using the following code.
But for some reason it does not work anymore and ALWAYS raises the error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

I am using Microsoft.Web.WebView2 from Nuget.

I have put a WebView2 on my form, and its name is WebView2.

Here is my code:

```
Private Async Sub PDFViewer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Debug.WriteLine("before InitializeAsync")
    Await (InitializeAsync())
    Debug.WriteLine("after InitializeAsync")

    Dim pdfBytes() As Byte
    pdfBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("somefile.pdf")

    Dim pdfBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes)
    Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
                        </head>
                        <style>
                               body   {margin: 0;}
                               iframe {display: block; background: #000; border: none; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;}
                        </style>
                        <body>" & $"<iframe src=""data:Application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}"">" & "</iframe></body></html>"

    WebView2.NavigateToString(html) 'here the error is thrown

End Sub
```

It works fine in Acrobat Reader and anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

WebView2 currently has a limit in NavigateToString.

Somewhere between 1.5 and 2 mb.

A workaround is to load the file locally.